# Sorting a nested string list for the second element (python)

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following problem. I have a nested list which contains football scores and their odds like it is shown in this short example.

```
scoreresultlist = [('1:0', '23.00'), ('0:0', '12.50'), ('0:1', '10.00'),('2:0', '36.00'), 
                  ('1:1', '9.50')]
```

Now I would like to sort the scores according to their odds. My problem is, that it is a nested list and all entries are saved as strings. Hope you can help and thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say odds you mean the first item in each tuple? How do you sort 1:0 vs 0:1?

Comment: I mean the second item of each tuple

Comment: Please show what you've tried? Can you provide an [mcve]? Otherwise, I'm afraid this question is to broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're really asking is to sort an array of tuples by their second element, which you can do by:

```
sorted_list = sorted(scoreresultlist, key=lambda element: Decimal(element[1]))
```

If you want to sort it in place, you can do

```
scoreresultlist.sort(key=lambda element: Decimal(element[1]))
```

(The `Decimal(element[1]))` type casts the string element to a `Decimal` for sorting purposes but does not modify the list.)

Comment: Note to you to import the `Decimal` class. `from decimal import Decimal`.